# How can i rewrite the axios promise module with only async/await syntax?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, axios

How can I rewrite the Axios promise module with only async/await syntax? Please
I'm new to Axios & promise, async syntax
=> what should i put inside the .push() ?

```
const axios = require("axios");
const _ = require("lodash");
const queue = require("queue");

// To control the request rate
const GetDataQueue_B = queue({ autostart: true, concur: 1 });
// someone's codes
const getDATA = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // To make sure only one request call
      GetDataQueue_B.push(
        async () => {
            try{
            const res = await axios.get(`${whichAPI}/api`);
            resolve(
                _.map(
                _.get(res, "data.infor"), 
                    obj => ({
                        quotes:obj.quotes,
                        author:boj.author,
                    })
                )
            );
            }catch(e) {reject(e);console.log(e);}
        }
      );
    });
```

below is my try: => what should i put inside the .push() ?

```
const getDATA_1 = async () => {
    try{
    const res = await axios.get(`${whichAPI}/api`);
    const data =  _.map(
                    _.get(res, "data.infor"), 
                        obj => ({
                            quotes:obj.quotes,
                            author:boj.author,
                        })
                    )                 
    GetDataQueue_B.push(); // => what should i put inside the .push() method?
    return data;
    }catch(e){console.log(e);}
  };
```

Comment: Is the code in the first code block really working the way it should be? It looks odd to have `getDATA` settle its promise as a side-effect from within the queued `async` function.

Comment: yep! it works but it doesn't belong to me. Im just trying to learn someone's code. & trying to rewrite it with async/await for easier understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queue` isn't the best choice here for clean code because while it allows pushing functions that return a promise, it itself doesn't return a promise, so you'd always be forced to use `new Promise` at some point and `resolve` it in its success callback or at the end of your own code. I guess that's the main reason why you are stuck with improving this code.

I recommend using [`p-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit) instead. It works like this:

```js
const pLimit = require("p-limit");

const myQueue = pLimit(5); // Allow only 5 things running in parallel

const promise = myQueue(async () => { /* stuff */ });
// promise will resolve once the passed function ran, and will return its
// result.
```

So, the code then looks like this:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const _ = require("lodash");
const pLimit = require("p-limit");

// To control the request rate
const GetDataQueue_B = pLimit(1);
// someone's codes
const getDATA = () => GetDataQueue_B(async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${whichAPI}/api`);
  return _.map(
    _.get(res, "data.infor"), 
      obj => ({
        quotes: obj.quotes,
        author: boj.author,
      })
    )
  );
});
```

I removed the `try`/`catch` because in the new version it wouldn't really do anything - an error here would reject the resulting promise anyway.

---

Side note: Using `lodash` is unnecessary here. It's always good to keep dependencies at a minimum and use built-in functionality instead. We could rewrite the code without `lodash` as follows:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const pLimit = require("p-limit");

// To control the request rate
const GetDataQueue_B = pLimit(1);
// someone's codes
const getDATA = () => GetDataQueue_B(async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${whichAPI}/api`);
  return res.data?.infor?.map(({ quotes, author }) => ({ quotes, author })) ?? [];
});
```

If you were sure that the `res.data.infor` array exists and you also wouldn't care about extra properties other than `quotes` and `author` in the result, this could be simplified even further:

```js
const getDATA = () => GetDataQueue_B(async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${whichAPI}/api`);
  return res.data.infor;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @CherryDT, you just open my eyes.

Comment: So as i see, basically, require("queue") & require("p-limit") just do almost the same thing with concurrent calls to API.
How about handling errors? Do you have any idea? the owner of this code uses @sentry/node & try-catch for real-time tracking errors.

Comment: It depends on the caller of `getDATA`. They will receive a rejected promise or - if they `await`ed the call - an exception, it's up to them what to do with it. If it's part of some HTTP route handling, it's built correctly to let errors bubble up and there is also some middleware that will report any errors from route handlers with sentry, it would just work, for example.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again! But is it possible to interval time between Jobs in Queue/P-limit in order to for example run only one job each second? If yes, how could I do that?

Comment: Use the more potent package [`p-queue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue) which has options `interval`/`intervalCap` which do exactly that.

Comment: thank you so much @CherryDT, you re amazing! :)
& have a good week